# How can i trigger push notification automatically to my food delivery web application from server to the desired users only?

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I tried using one signal, fcm but i have to target manually whom i want to send the notification which should not be the case. The notifications should be triggered automatically everytime a user places an order to a specific restaurant and not to all restaurant.

one signal, fcm, pusher beams , pushalerts

```
public class MyService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

        sendNotification(notification, data);
    }
```

expected results are the notification should go  to targeted restaurants only rather than going in all other restaurants. actuals results are i have to trigger manually to send to particular restaurants from user app which is not appropriate in terms of app development

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for info on how to integrate your backend events with OneSignal. You can use our API for this. Take a look at our [blog post](https://onesignal.com/blog/data-integration-and-tagging-using-onesignal/) explaining how you can achieve your desired result.